# How to add Text to multiple videos with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, drawtext

How to add Text to multiple videos with ffmpeg

```
......... File.txt..
file 'Vidos1.mkv' -vf "drawtext=text='Good ':x=0:y=h-th:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" 
file 'Vidos2.mkv' -vf "drawtext=text='God':x=0:y=h-th:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" 
file 'Vidos3.mkv' -vf "drawtext=text='Go':x=0:y=h-th:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" 
......... File.txt..


ffmpeg  -f concat -safe 0 -re -i /File.txt ............
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reset PTS, then use drawtext filter and concat.

```
ffmpeg -i Vidos1.mkv -i Vidos2.mkv -i Vidos3.mkv -filter_complex \
   "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,drawtext=text='Good ':x=0:y=h-th:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white[0v];\
    [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,drawtext=text='God ':x=0:y=h-th:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white[1v];\
    [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,drawtext=text='Go ':x=0:y=h-th:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white[2v];\
    [0:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[0a];[1:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1a];[2:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[2a];\
    [0v][0a][1v][1a][2v][2a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" ...
```

Comment: Can I do this with 50 videos?   [0:v].....[50:v] ....... [0:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[0a];[1:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1a];...........[50:a]

Comment: Yes. Another way is to concatenate them with the concat filter, and then specify them by time in the timeline editing of the drawtext filter. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing

Comment: I have an mkv movie. I could not get the Languages and Subtitles of this file with map. I want to stream subtitles and audios with rtmp as well. do you have a suggestion

Comment: What kind of mkv file is that? Show me the console logs. ```ffmpeg -i Vidos1.mkv```